# Invalid parameter number when paginate with knp-paginator

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

I'm using Symfony 2.3.20, with knp-paginator 2.4.1, knp-components 1.3.1 and doctrine orm 2.3.6
Everything was working fine, until i ran composer update, calling the following paginate from paginator return an invalid parameter number exception (everything was fine before composer update) ... Some help please
`return $paginator->paginate($Query, $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 10, array('pageParameterName' => 'page'));`

The stack trace

```
[1] Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
at n/a
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php line 69

at Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::invalidParameterNumber()
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query.php line 255

at Doctrine\ORM\Query->_doExecute()
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php line 753

at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute(null, '3')
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php line 566

at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getScalarResult()
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator.php line 144

at Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator->count()
    in  line 

at count(object(Paginator))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\knplabs\knp-components\src\Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\Doctrine\ORM\QuerySubscriber\UsesPaginator.php line 43

at Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\Doctrine\ORM\QuerySubscriber\UsesPaginator->items(object(ItemsEvent))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(array(object(UsesPaginator), 'items'), object(ItemsEvent))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 1665

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(QueryBuilderSubscriber), 'items'), array(object(QueryBuilderSubscriber), 'items'), array(object(DBALQueryBuilderSubscriber), 'items'), array(object(QuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(QuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(ElasticaQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(PropelQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(SolariumQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(PropelQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(UsesPaginator), 'items'), array(object(QuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(QuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(CollectionSubscriber), 'items'), array(object(PropelQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(SolariumQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(ElasticaQuerySubscriber), 'items'), array(object(ArraySubscriber), 'items')), 'knp_pager.items', object(ItemsEvent))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 1598

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('knp_pager.items', object(ItemsEvent))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 1762

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('knp_pager.items', object(ItemsEvent))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\vendor\knplabs\knp-components\src\Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator.php line 108

at Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator->paginate(object(Query), '1', '10', array('pageParameterName' => 'page'))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\src\Wmn\MainBundle\Controller\MainController.php line 405

at Wmn\MainBundle\Controller\MainController->searchHotels('hilton', null, null, null, null)
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\src\Wmn\MainBundle\Controller\MainController.php line 182

at Wmn\MainBundle\Controller\MainController->searchResultsAction(null, null)
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(MainController), 'searchResultsAction'), array(null, null))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2891

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2865

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2994

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2274

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\wmn-rest\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back to knp components 1.2.5 from composer, and everything works like a charm :-)